# Crash using memcpy/memmove repeatedly

Tags: c++

So I have this litte code, It loops through memory regions, saves them to a byte array, then uses it and finally deletes it (deallocate it). This all happens in a non-main thread, therefore the use of CriticalSections.

Code looks like this:

```
SIZE_T addr_min = (SIZE_T)sysInfo.lpMinimumApplicationAddress;
SIZE_T addr_max = (SIZE_T)sysInfo.lpMaximumApplicationAddress;

while (addr_min < addr_max)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi = { 0 };
    if (!::VirtualQueryEx(hndl, (LPCVOID)addr_min, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && ((mbi.Protect & PAGE_GUARD) == 0) && ((mbi.Protect & PAGE_NOACCESS) == 0))
    {

        SIZE_T region_size = mbi.RegionSize;
        PVOID Base_Address = mbi.BaseAddress;

        BYTE * dump = new BYTE[region_size + 1];

        EnterCriticalSection(...);

        memset(dump, 0x00, region_size + 1);

        //this is where it crashes, same thing with memcpy
        //Access violation reading "dump"'s address:
        //memmove(unsigned char * dst=0x42aff024, unsigned char * 
        //src=0x7a768000, unsigned long count=1409024)

        std::memmove(dump, Base_Address, region_size); 

        LeaveCriticalSection(...);

        //Do Stuff with dump, that only involves reading from it

        if (dump){
            delete[] dump;
            dump = NULL;
        }
    }
    addr_min += mbi.RegionSize;

}
```

Code works fine most of the time. But sometimes it just crashes in memcpy/memmove. Under the Visual Studio Debugger it shows that the crash is because there is a error reading "dump", how is that possible if I just define and allocated memory for it. Thanks!

Also, could it be because memory can change in the middle of memcpy?

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that you have another thread that is double deleting a pointer, and that pointer happens to have the same value as `dump`. Try moving the `EnterCriticalSection` up before the `new` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Why is the critical section where it is?  If it is protecting the source region then you entered it too late... and dump is local to this thread so there is no need to protect dump

Comment: @MarkRansom Could this be solved by checking if dump is valid/accesible somehow? Thanks! edit: saw your edited comment. I will do that, thanks!

Comment: @M.M Okay, so the critical section is useless then.

Comment: Have a look at [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f9c3860a-d716-4b79-b810-4458d65d4631/can-i-check-if-a-pointer-is-valid?forum=vclanguage) to see what can be done to validate the pointer. But that just helps you narrow down the problem, you still have a bug elsewhere in your program that you need to find.

Comment: @MarkRansom Makes sense, many other things could get allocated at the same time as "dump" in other parts of the program. I will critical section before allocating that memory. Thanks!

Comment: Does hndl relate to this process?  The critical section is insufficient to protect - other parts of your memory maybe mapped in and out especially with new / delete being performed in loop

Comment: Looks like Critical Sections are useless in this case. This is the only thread running, and the thread never writes to anything external. Only performs reads, every writing I do, is to internal code.